# How to use makecert to create a self signed certiciate

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, ws-security

I am having difficulty using makecert. Can anyone help?

`makecert -sk MyKeyName -iv RootCATest.pvk -n "CN=tempCert" -ic RootCATest.cer -sr localmachine -ss my -sky exchange -pe`

I am trying to create Temporary Certificates in WCF for Message Security as per the instruction on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647171.aspx

1. `makecert -n "CN=RootCATest" -r -sv RootCATest.pvk RootCATest.cer` ( successfully created RootCATest.cer, RootCATest.pvk)
2. `makecert -sk MyKeyName -iv RootCATest.pvk -n "CN=tempCert" -ic RootCATest.cer -sr localmachine -ss my -sky exchange -pe`

Unable to create temporary certificate with step 2. If I removed `-pe` then it is sucessfully creating, but `-pe` is mandatory in my requirement.

Am I missing any thing or please help me. I tried in both Windows Xp and Win 7  but no luck.

Comment: What error message do you see on step 2?

Comment: Usage: MakeCert [ basic|extended options] [outputCertificateFile] Basic Options. Getting again usage info after running makecert with -pe option. Iam using VS2008 on Windows 7 makecert available in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\SmartDevices\SDK\SDKTools location. the command which i used : makecert -sk MyKeyName -iv RootCATest.pvk -n "CN=tempCert" -ic RootCATest.cer -sr localmachine -ss my -sky exchange -pe

Answer (score 3):

i found the issue from http://www.inventec.ch/chdh/notes/14.htm. I downloaded latest version of makecert and sucessfully able to create temp certifcate.

Comment: Is the answser actually that you had a version of makecert that did not support -pe? How did you change what you where doing? What is the actual answer?